# Como subir um projeto em Nuxt para um servidor? (Namecheap)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, deploy

pessoal quais os arquivos de um projeto em nuxt devo subir para um servidor, no caso utilizo o namecheap.

rodei o `npm run build` (na minha máquina), e uma pasta **/dist** foi criada dentro da pasta **.nuxt**

li a documentação e algumas coisas a respeito mas realmente não entendi ainda como devo proceder.

Comment: Tudo depende da sua arquitetura e o modo do Nuxt que você está utilizando. Aqui nós subimos todos os arquivos e executamos `npm run build` e `npm start` com o Jenkins.

Comment: entendi. estou usando no modo universal (ssr). mas vocês sobem todos os arquivos e pastas mesmo? (/.nuxt, /assets, /components, /layouts, etc...). vocês rodam `npm run build` ainda na máquina para criar a pasta dist dentro de .nuxt ou só rodam este comando após subir tudo para o servidor?

Comment: Na nossa arquitetura subimos tudo para um servidor git e o docker pega a aplicação e roda um `npm install`, `npm run build` e `npm start`. Porém recomendo você dar uma olhada [aqui](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/commands/#server-rendered-deployment-universal-). Pelo que entendo da arquitetura do Nuxt, você vai precisar apenas da pasta `.nuxt`

Answer (score -1):

Geralmente eu uso `npm run generate`, ele gera arquivos estáticos na pasta dist, e esses arquivos coloco numa hospedagem.

Pode usar o `npm run build` também, mas ele vai gerar os arquivos minificados.